# Proper way to identify member devices in mdadm.conf

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, uuid, block-device

My current mdadm.conf looks like:

```
$ cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
DEVICE /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 spares=0 UUID=357ff7cc:55e78d18:9fc7917b:f5b253f2
MAILADDR me@example.com
```

Since upgrading the kernel from a 2.6.x to some 3.x, I noticed block devices would get random names at each boot. This fantastic new trouble can generally be worked around by assigning UUIDs to filesystems and swap partitions and reference them by fstab and Grub; but how do I reference block devices members of a raid from `mdadm.conf`? While array members usually contain a filesystem, their UUIDs may be duplicate (raid 1) or non-existent.

From my example above, how would you replace `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdc1`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use "DEVICE partitions", it will try all devices listed in /proc/partitions, and you wouldn't have to worry at all what the device names are. UUID of an array is stored on each device belonging to it, so each array will be assembled correctly even if you have several of them.